# Missing logs for Tizen application, sdb shows nothing

Tags: debugging, logging, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator

I am writing a Tizen NUI application and I am testing it on a TV emulator. I've gone through the whole ordeal of creating and installing developer certificates, now my application deploys and runs on the emulator. However, I see no logs. Not in the Tizen Device Manager, not in Visual Studio's Tizen Logs output, nothing.

I tried to manually obtain the logs with sdb, but it didn't work. When I try to run

```
sdb shell
```

I get the output

```
closed
closed
```

which is not telling me much.

When I give

```
sdb dlog
```

I see

```
- waiting for device -
closed
- waiting for device -
closed
- waiting for device -
....
```

and so on.

I would be grateful if anyone has any idea on how to go forward. I should have access to a real TV soon, but until then I'd like to be able to continue working nonetheless.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid TVs are a 'special case' in Tizen ecosystem. Lot of Tizen APIs and features are disabled in Tizen TVs

Here you can check the answer in Tizen support forums to a similar question

*sdb shell in Tizen TV is not supported for the security reason. It is only allow to provide Samsung Smart TV Partner Developers.
Best Regards
Tizen TV SDK team*

In TV web apps the best way is to use the browser console.log() and inspector